# Rolling Time Series Forecasting with data on underperforming year such as COVID scenario i.e. 2020

Tags: time-series, forecasting, validation, trend

Recently I am working on a project where I am to forecast volume and sales of merchandise as well as fuel.

While streamlining my thoughts and the method to go ahead with the exercise I realized that if I forecast monthly volume using past years' data for the next 12 months will my forecasts be biased somehow, considering 2020 had been a weird year and the trends were all messed up compared to the previous year?

Also, when I am building the model, train it on previous years and test it on the most recent year i.e. 2020 , the MAPE might be huge because this year was "unpredictable"

My question is how to overcome these two problems?

P. S. Only time series models are allowed, I cannot use any other ML models

Comment: I have this problem with my forecast.I use last month forecast error to adjust the projections for the future forecast. Or did, now the time series has adjusted itself (or the process returned to normal) so it not longer needs this. This is for ESM and ARIMA. Also this was a personal guess on my part of what would work. I have not seen this suggested in the literature. In the literature I think they would suggest replacing past months in the unusual period with the numbers you think they would be without the problem. But if your data changes a lot over time as our does it is hard to do that.

Comment: That are two good ideas. Adjusting future forecasts from the previous errors : Won't this be a very subjective procedure? What do you think can be done when you have 30-40 different time series and the process needs to be automated?

Comment: I am sure it is subjective. I just don't have any alternatives :) Creating an adjustment ratio to deal with error   and using it to modify the results of the time series is not very time consuming and that is what I did. I wish I could tell you precisely how well it worked, but I honestly forget.

Comment: Others have asked the same question:  https://www.eyeon.nl/mid-long-term-demand-forecasting-in-times-of-covid-19/